# Read file and split each line into multiple variable in C++

Tags: c++

I have a file of this type:

```
key1#value1#value2##
key2#value3#value4#value5##
key3#value6##
etc.
```

I need to read each line, and separate key and values. I've tried different approaches (`istringstream & iterator` - but I don't know how to explicitly define # as the separator), double `getline`, I read about `boost` libraries but I am not sure I would be able to compile it.

I thought another way to do it would be to separate each line into a vector. The first element will always be the key, and vector's size will determine how many values each line had.

What is the best way to split each line?

Comment: This question already has an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946558/c-read-from-text-file-and-separate-into-variable

Comment: @Tejendra Incorrect. The mentioned answers does not cover custom delimiter settings, which is in fact the question here.

Comment: @Tejendra, the question you linked only provides an answer if the file format uses a value separator (`s`) for which `std::isspace(s)` evaluates to true (tokens separated by spaces, tabs, etc).

Comment: Hey, SO people! Why do you downvote _every_ _single_ question regardless of it's worthy or not? I simply don't get why a question about delimiter usage with C++ streams  deserve a downvote..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the best way to split each line?

I would simply call `while(std::getline(stream, line)` to read each line, then for each read line, I would put it into a istringstream (`iss`), and call `while(std::getline(iss, value, '#'))` repeatedly (with `stream` being your initial stream, and `line` and `value` being strings). The first value read in the inner loop will be the key; the rest, will be the values.

Some code:

```
auto read_file(std::istream& in)
{
    using namespace std;
    map<string, vector<string>> values;
    string line;
    while(getline(in, line))
    {
        istringstream linein{ line };
        string key, value;
        if(!getline(linein, key, '#'))
            throw runtime_error{ "bad file format" };
        while(getline(linein, value, '#') && !value.empty())
            values[key].emplace_back(move(value));
    }
    return values;
}

std::ifstream in{ "file-of-this-type.txt" };
auto values = read_file(in);
```

Comment: And probably store everything in a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get each line as a String. After that use this information [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c) It's very useful